# Ignoring fields when unmarshalling using Castor XML Mapping

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling, castor

I need to convert a XML to an object (Unmarshalling), but there is a field (tag) that I don´t want it to be mapped. I have been looking for an answer in StackOverFlow but only found how to convert an object to a XML (Marshalling) and I need to know about (Unmarshalling). Here is the XML:

```
<autorizacion>
    <estado>AUTORIZADO</estado>
    <numeroAutorizacion>9999999999999</numeroAutorizacion>
    <fechaAutorizacion>17/06/2015</fechaAutorizacion>
    <comprobante>
<comprobanteRetencion id="comprobante" version="1.0.0">
   <infoAdicional>
    <campoAdicional nombre="correo:">jeje@hotmail.com</campoAdicional>
  </infoAdicional>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:etsi="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Id="Signature89637">
<ds:KeyInfo Id="Certifixxxxxx0">
<ds:Modulus>
ppFiiWXmjvwteDiLvklh38gGypZ8moRjEhEijs0kfjpddd1NTJ5QWmNtgH8uVUP5aEduxPMYQPpg
</ds:Modulus>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
</comprobanteRetencion>
</comprobante>
</autorizacion>
```

I want to exclude the tag Signature from the unmarshalling process.

Herer is the mapping XML:

```
<class name="ec.eac.sitac.esigef.ComprobanteRetencion" auto-complete="true">
    <map-to xml="comprobanteRetencion" />
    <field name="infoAdicional" type="ec.eac.sitac.esigef.InfoAdicional">
        <bind-xml name="infoAdicional" node="element" />
    </field>
</class>
```

Comment: do you found the answer?  ;-)

Comment: Yes, I found it. I Just added the answer. Maybe it was not an elegant solution, but it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the tag by using:

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(xmlPath);

        Node node = xml.getElementsByTagName("comprobanteRetencion").item(0);
        Node signature = node.getLastChild();
        node.removeChild(signature);
```

Answer (score 1):

Any unmapped element will be ignored, unless you validate against a schema.

Example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="A")
public class A {
    @XmlElement(name="B")
    String b;
}
```

Test code:

```
String xml = "<A><B>Hello</B><C>World</C></A>";
JAXBContext jaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxb.createUnmarshaller();
A a = (A)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
System.out.println(a.b);
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

As you can see, the value of `<B>` was unmarshalled, and the value of `<C>` got ignored.

**Update**

To explicitly ignore the value of `<C>`, add a dummy setter method:

```
@XmlElement(name="C")
void setC(String c) {/*ignore*/}
```

Comment: I mapped all the tags except the "Signature" tag, and when I run my application I got the following error: unable to find FieldDescriptor for Signature...

Comment: I´m not using java annotation, I´m using xml configuration file. How can I exclude a tag using an xml configuration file?

Comment: The xml mappings are still mapping to setter method, so just map to dummy setter method.

Comment: 1-Added a field to ComprobanteRetencion xml mapping file
2-Adden an attribute to the java class ComprobanteRetencion
3-Added an empty setSignature method

>Still getting the error:UnmarshallingFailureException: SAX reader exception; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXException: unable to find FieldDescriptor for 'Signature' in ClassDescriptor of comprobanteRetencion